# Drag file onto program icon for processing?

Tags: javascript, macos, applescript

The ideal scenario:

1. The user drags a collection of SVGs onto the program’s icon;
2. the program checks to make sure all submitted files are indeed SVGs;
3. the program checks for a local installation of SVGO; and
4. the program processes the files with SVGO using a YAML config script and this command: `svgo -f ./ -o ./optimized --config=./svgo.yml`

I’m using [SVGO](https://github.com/svg/svgo) for SVG optimization and compression. It can to be installed globally or local to the project.

Where should I start regarding the drag and drop piece? I’m much more familiar with JavaScript than AppleScript and was looking for a Node/JS + AppleScript implementation that could handle the task.

Comment: Maybe you can create your wrapper app with [Automator](https://support.apple.com/guide/automator/welcome). I don’t know if it has a “receive dropped files” action, but it does have a “run shell script” action that can pass files as arguments, and Automator does support creating a stand-alone app.

Answer (score 0):

In AppleScript Editor, just use the "on open" handler :

```
 on open myItems
   repeat with one_item in myItems
     -- do what you need to do here for each file

   end repeat
 end open
```

Save your script as application (save as option). Each file or list of files dropped on the script/application icon will be processed as "one_item".

Answer (score 0):

If by "program" you're referring the an AppleScript application that's going to do the processing, then have a look at: [Processing Dropped Files and Folders](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/MacAutomationScriptingGuide/ProcessDroppedFilesandFolders.html)

Here's a cropped screenshot of the top part of the page:

[image]